# Undefined variable in view after adding it to controller

Tags: php, laravel

The error is:

> Undefined variable: room_state (View:
>   /var/app/current/resources/views/pages/room.blade.php)

In my controller I have:

```
    $room_state = 1;
$rooms = DB::table('room')->select('*')->where('room_id', '=', $room_id)->get();
    $doors = DB::table('door')->select('*')->where('room_id', '=', $room_id)->get();
foreach ($rooms as $room) {
    if (empty(session()->get('user.rooms')) || ! in_array($room->room_id, session()->get('user.rooms')) ) {
        session()->push('user.rooms', $room->room_id); 
        $room_state = 0;
    }
    else {
        $room_state = 1;
    }
}
return view('pages/room', ['rooms' => $rooms], ['doors' => $doors], ['room_state' => $room_state]  );
```

In my view, I have:

```
    <p>Room State: {{ $room_state }}</p>
```

My view was working before I added the room state to return, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing multiple parameters instead of a single parameter with all keyvalue pairs to your `view()` call.

Do this instead:

```
return view('pages/room', ['rooms' => $rooms, 'doors' => $doors, 'room_state' => $room_state]);
```

Or, simply use `compact()` since the variable names are the same as the key names:

```
return view('pages/room', compact('rooms', 'doors', 'room_state'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to return the values in just one array

```
return view('pages/room', ['rooms' => $rooms,'doors' => $doors, 'room_state' => $room_state]);
```

or you use compact

```
return view('pages/room', compact('rooms', 'doors', 'room_state));
```